# mod_rewrite rule not sending $_GET PHP parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've seen a couple other questions similar to this, but the answers are not working for me. Hopefully someone can shed some light.

I have a URL like `http://website.com/show/?id=9999` and I use `$_GET['id']` in a PHP script on the page. When I use a rewrite rule to convert the URL to `http://website.com/show/9999/` then `$_GET['id']` is no longer working.

Here's the rewrite rules I'm using:

```
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^show/(.*)$ /show/?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Why do you have "! -f" *and* "!-d"?

Comment: Check the RewriteLog to uncover the loop and how `(.*)` eats up your parameter.

Comment: The !-f and !-d mean "not a literal file" and "not a literal directory". This lets stylesheets, images, mp3's, javascript, etc be displayed without rewrite rules interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah! Fixed it. I left out a key piece of info, which is that `http://website.com/show/` is also rewritten through the WordPress permalink engine.  The "L" flag in my rule was preventing the target from being picked up again by the WordPress rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want those rewrite conditions. You just need the rule. This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^show/([^/]*)$ /show/?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Without the rewriteCond's, images, stylesheets, javascript, and other static assets will not be accessible. -1

Comment: @Adrianopolis, that gave me an 500 internal server error.  Is it a problem that `http://website.com/show/` is also a URL that's been rewritten by WordPress?  WP rewrites that `http://website.com/?p=540` with it's permalink engine.

Comment: Hi Brian... I didn't realize you were using wordpress. And in regards to mpsyd comment on assets not working... Not sure about that. I've never had my assets break using the simple rewrite rule format I gave to you. Again though not sure about wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

The `$_GET['id']` is no longer working, because the `id` parameter is no longer part of the get string. The apache rewrite happens at a lower layer of the web stack than php operates, which means that there is no longer a `$_GET` string at all by the time php takes over. You can test this with `var_dump($_GET);` and see for yourself.

That stated, it can be accessed via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` by doing the following:

```
$params = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
var_dump($params[0]); //This should print "show"
var_dump($params[1]); //This should print "9999"
```

You will need to be able to anticipate which segment of the URL corresponds to the value you require to do it this way. This is typically the job of a router.

Example: http://upshots.org/php/php-seriously-simple-router

Comment: I tested with `var_dumb($_GET);`, nothing.  But isn't apache rewriting the URL so it interprets it as `website.com/show/?id=9999` thus the query string would be present? Why isn't that happening?

Comment: Apache is the first layer of the stack. Php doesn't know what the url is until after apache is done manipulating it. When php loads, the superglobals get declared based on what apache hands them, so what apache sees and what php sees are not the same thing. You'll need to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get it if you are going to keep the rewrite rule.